# VBA XML file load error when filename has URL encoding

Tags: xml, vba

I'm working in VBA and using Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0 to read and parse XML files.  It is mostly working, except some filenames have URL style encoding in the filenames.  For example, a filename is like:

HelloWorld%2Ecom.xml

My code cannot find the file when I try to load this.  Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
Dim filename as String
filename = "HelloWorld%2Ecom.xml" ' This variable is actually populated dynamically
Dim objXML As Variant
Set objXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
objXML.async = True
objXML.Load filename
```

The specific error I get during the Load operation is:

Error while loading XML file: The system cannot locate the object specified.

If I manually remove the % sign from the filename, the file loads fine.  However, I really need to keep the original filenames.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Mike

Comment: You absolutely could use `%` in reading/writing file names. Be sure you use entire path name in `Load` statement.

Comment: However, it absolutely does not work.  Also tried escaping the % with another % and it still can't find the file:  HelloWorld%%2Ecom.xml gives the same error...

Comment: How about using the Replace function within your code (so that you don't need to change the actual file names) to replace the % with a space: strFileName = Replace(filename, "%", " ")

Comment: @MikePaisner, I tested to be sure by adding a percent to an existing xml file and loaded without error. Windows file paths disallow the following [reserved characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): < > : " / \ | ? *. Again, check **full** path. Does such a file exist in a CPU directory (not URL)?

Comment: My code works for all files in the folder except ones with % sign in filename, so the path is good.  When I manually remove % from filename, then it works fine.  I tried using filesystemobject to rename the file using the move command, but I get the same error.  I cannot programmatically rename a file with the % sign in the name because it cannot find that file.

Comment: To clarify, it is not just the % sign in the filename that causes the problem.  It is only when a URL code is in the filename like %2E is in the filename.

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured it out.  Needed to urlencode the filename before loading.

Instead of this line above:

```
objXML.Load filename
```

I changed it to the following:

```
dim encodedName as String
encodedName = WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(filename)
objXML.Load encodedName
```

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, escape the percent sign with `%25`:

```
filename = "HelloWorld%252Ecom.xml"
```